# Precompile slim templates using the rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, slim-lang

It would be super handy if I could precompile slim templates using the rails asset pipeline. I was hoping to stick my templates in app/assets/html and serve them up that way.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# config/initializers/slim.rb
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)

# config/application.rb
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/html"
config.assets.register_mime_type('text/html', '.html')
```

Running rake assets:precompile reads the .html.slim files in app/assets/html but it doesn't compile them and the output file still has the .slim extension.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @kurt-mueller is correct but needs to be updated for Rails 4 with Sprockets 3+. There was a change in Sprockets that means the `assets` property is not present during initialisation. Instead you can do:

```
# config/initializers/slim.rb

Rails.application.config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.config.assets.configure do |env|
    env.register_engine(".slim", Slim::Template)
  end
end
```

Comment: Updated my answer to use the [recommended method](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/307#issuecomment-170707886).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm tardy to the party, but Dillon Buchanan answered this question [here](http://www.dillonbuchanan.com/programming/rails-slim-templates-in-the-asset-pipeline/).

Go to the `config/initializers` directory and create a file like `slim_assets.rb` (or something similar) and copy-pasta the following line:

```
Rails.application.assets.register_engine('.slim', Slim::Template)
```

I've done something similar with great success with HAML (which I use to write templates for Rails/AngJS apps).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add the new path like this on `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ["*.js", "*.css", "*.slim"]  #whatever you need
```

Answer (score -1):

you need add the static files into precompile array:

config.assets.precompile += %w( vendor/modernizr 404.html )